# Why is it throwing out_of_range error?

Tags: c++, string, getline

```
int main()
{       
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin,s); 
        cout<<s.at(0);          
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run this code but it says out_of_range error. This code is not even taking in the string input.

Comment: *This code is not even taking in the string input.* -- That's the reason.  Your string is empty and you're trying to access the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing **line-based** input with **non-line-based** input.

> ```
> int main()
> {       
>     int t;
>     cin>>t;
> ```

When the user enters "123" and then presses the enter key, the "123" part of the input is parsed and ends up as the number 123 in `t`, but the linebreak resulting from the enter key will remain in the input buffer.

That's non-line-based input.

> ```
> while(t--) {
>     string s;
>     getline(cin,s);
> ```

The `std::getline` function reads everything until a linebreak is encountered. The linebreak from above is still there, so a linebreak is encountered *immediately* and `s` remains empty.

That's line-based input.

`std::getline` also consumes the linebreak it has encountered, but this doesn't help you much anymore:

> ```
>    cout<<s.at(0);
> ```

`s` has size 0 and `at(0)` tries to access the 1st element. [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) is required to throw `std::out_of_range_error` when you try to access a non-existing element.

---

A good solution would be to switch exclusively to line-based input on the top input layer. Read everything as lines and parse the individual lines as required. Use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert a string to an integer number.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{       
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    int t = std::stoi(input);

    while(t--)
    {
        std::string s;
        getline(std::cin, s); 
        std::cout << s.at(0);          
    }    
}
```

Note that you should consider adding more error handling to your code. What happens when the user enters a negative number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cin.sync()` function to clear extra input buffer.

The code like this:

```
int main()
{       
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.sync(); // add this line
    while(t--)
    {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s); 
        cout<<s.at(0);          
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

The original code to make the string that is empty and you're trying to access the first element. So it says out_of_range error.